# How to make modern SharePoint site full width

Tags: css, html, designer

Has anyone had any luck in making their modern SP site utilise the full width of the web page? I have a requirement to embed the "Planner" app onto a SP site, but would like to also remove the massive amount of unused blank space to the right of the page.

[image]

I've managed to make a classic SP site full width, but unable to embed Planner into it.

I'm not too fussed as to how I get to the solution, be it a classic or modern site. I just need a way of having a full width site with Planner on it. Any ideas welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: The article is only relevant to communications sites. Teams sites are a different matter due to the Left menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no OOTB feature to extend the Modern UI to full width, if you want you can implement using SPFx [Article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column)

And there is no feature to add the custom CSS in the Modern page.

so my suggestion is change the layout to one-third right and you can utilize the right side for some other static content.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.

Unfortunately the one-third right suggestion just makes the available space for Planner even less, so I don't think that's an option on this occasion.

The PlannerWebPart has already got supportsFullBleed set to true. I imagine it's the actual column it sits in that I need to set to full width as opposed to the app itself. Is it not possible to edit this using SharePoint Designer at all?

Comment: Yes, it not possible even through SharePoint Designer because Modern UI created based on the themes. we can decorative the site but not customization , and Modern UI doesn't have any site definition to modify at code level

Comment: Four years later and I'm still trying to figure out how to use my entire fucking screen.  Hey Microsoft, NOT EVERYONE IS ON A PHONE OR TABLET!