# How to make a webpart in SP online Modern Experience full width

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I am trying to make a webpart full width but there is no option for it.
All the options that I can see are as below:
[image]

1-I have found this old question, is there any update here"

[How to make modern SharePoint site full width](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249746/how-to-make-modern-sharepoint-site-full-width)

2-Found this solution:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column

but is there any better solution without modifying the code nor developing an SPFx?

3-and this one too:

https://regroove.ca/karin/full-width-hero-web-part-sharepoint-online/

but my site does not have Full size as shown in the above screenshot?

I created this site by creating a team in MS team so I assume it is a Team site and not a communication site.

Comment: is it a communication site?

Comment: No, it is not communication site

Comment: another question:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297287/where-is-manifest-josn-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: Which web part are you trying to use? Are you using SharePoint out of the box web parts?

Comment: Yes, I have to use one of the out-of-the-box solutions, due to the complexity of our environment I cannot develop a package in SPFx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full-width column is currently available only for Communication Site, and there is no OOB way to make a modern web part full-width in team site without code.

[image]