# where is manifest.josn in sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part

I am trying to make the web part of my website full width based on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205499/simply-edit-sharepoint-webpart-manifest-json

and have found this solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205499/simply-edit-sharepoint-webpart-manifest-json

but cannot find the src folder when I open our SP site in SP Designer 2013 as shown below
[image]

Where or how can I edit this Manifest.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in web part didn't release the source code, if you want to modify the property, it's necessary to build a custom SPFX Web Part with Node.js. And you can find some sample SPFX Web Part source code from GitHub: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples.

If you are going to edit the Manifest.json of your custom SPFX web part, you have to get the source project file of it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find the same thing! Other examples I'm finding are local instances of manifest.json, but I want to add an iframe to the full-width container. The only thing close is [what MS suggests here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column) (but still doesn't help me find the JSON file on the server.